# SQL Select add static text but not on last record

Tags: php, sql

How can I statically extend the result of an sql select but leaving out the static text extension at the last record?

I have this code

```
"SELECT field FROM table" ; "" ; " \\"
```

Lets say I have 3 records and each of the 3 records hold one letter:

```
a, b, c
```

then I get this result:

```
a \b \c \
```

but I want

```
a \b \c
```

how can I use select to leave out the last "\"

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT MySQL function;

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(field SEPARATOR '\\') as fields FROM  table;
```

Edit: Need to use double \ to escape.